# How can I change the "Dim the display" and "Dimming display brightness" setting (Windows) from wihin my application?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

My application is already able to set the timeout when display should turn off, as well as setting the all over, and also to set the current brightness in general. Windows has an additional feature that dims the display after some time (the "Dim the display after" and "Display dimming brightness" in the advanced power scheme settings).

Does anybody knows how I can query/set the options "Dim display after" and "Display dimming brightness" settings from within my application (its a C/C++ application)- if possible by using "pure" Windows API?

Have much thanks in before.
Yours Willi K.

Comment: Please note: Please do not make suggestions like "Call 'powercfg {...}'" - from my point of view calling another program to do somethings is not the right way to resolve a problem.

Comment: Explore power management interfaces rather than the `SetMonitorBrightness` function.

Comment: I do not use SetMonitorBrightness() function. Can you give me more details about the "Power Management Interface", especially for the options I am looking for, please?

Comment: [Here you go](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373163(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Have much thanks, Ron. This pointed me in the right direction. I just also found [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566830/using-windows-power-management-api-to-dim-monitor) which seems to describe what I am looking for. If I got the soltion, I will leave a code example.

Comment: By your help I got the solution, Ron. How can I honor your help w/o posting the solution by myself (in meaning of leaving an code expamle for others)?.
My solution implies PowerGetActiveScheme(), PowerReadACValue()/PowerReadDCValue(), PowerWriteACValueIndex()/PowerWriteDCValueIndex() and PowerSetActiveScheme() (which applyies the settings) via GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP, GUID_VIDEO_DIM_TIMEOUT and GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_DIM_BRIGHTNESS.

Comment: Feel free to post the answer yourself.

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) Yes! And since you have working code, you are in a very good position to provide a good answer, already verified to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ron pointed me in the right direction. Following code expample shows, how an application can control when the backlight should dim to a specific brightness level (error checking etc. has been omitted in order to make code more easy to understand).

```
#include <iniitguid.h>    // Seems to be uncluded before Windows.h for some reason...
#include <windows.h>
#include <powrprof.h>

static const GUID GuidPwrVideoIf = GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP;
static const GUID GuidPwrDimTimeout = GUID_VIDEO_DIM_TIMEOUT;
static const GUID GuidPwrDimBrightness = GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_DIM_BRIGHTNESS;

void setBacklightDimming(DWORD timeOut, DWORD dimmedBrightness)
{
    DWORD ret;
    GUID *pGuidPwrActiveSheme;    

    // Attach to the active power scheme
    ret = PowerGetActiveScheme(NULL, &pGuidPwrActiveSheme);

    // Set the timeout that will elapse before the display will dim
    ret = PowerWriteDCValueIndex(NULL, pGuidPwrActiveSheme, &GuidPwrVideoIf, &GuidPwrDimTimeout, timeOut);

    // Set the dimmed brightness level
    PowerWriteDCValueIndex(NULL, pGuidPwrActiveSheme, &GuidPwrVideoIf, &GuidPwrDimBrightness, dimmedBrightness);

    // Apply the new setings immediately
    retVal = PowerSetActiveScheme(NULL, pGuidPwrActiveSheme);

    // Go on with whatever you want to do...
}
```

This code sample changes the settings when the system is "On battary" (e.g. a laptop). To set the settings when the system is "On AC power", simply replace PowerWrite*DC*ValueIndex() by PowerWrite**AC**ValueIndex().